# POST request not sending string to the database

Tags: php

I want to be able to read the raw data from the URL path. The URL will look like:

https://newtest.000webhostapp.com/db.php?datainurl

The db.php is:

```
<?php

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','2541','yhte','tg543');
    
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
    
$sql = "insert into cloud set rfid='.$postdata'";
    
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{
   echo "New record created successfully";
} 

else 
{
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

When I press enter in the URL the webpage echos: New record created successfully. I see the id in the database but the contents is not shown in the database.

[image: Database]

Why the "datainurl" in the URL is not showing in the database?

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Use mysql_real_escape_string function or parameterised queries to avoid SQL injection attacks

Comment: @GrégoryC `mysql_real_escape_string ` has been removed ages ago. It's only prepared statements now.

Comment: @Dharman you are right thanks for this ;-) I hadn't use it since a long time as I work with Symfony/Doctrine

Answer (score 0):

The query string is available through `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

`php://input` contains the request *body*.